# How to change text color using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, function, colors

I'm trying to change text color depending on the number value.

```
<?php
        $secure_num = 8;
        $price_num = 4;
    
        <script>
            function change_color_text (num1) {
            var rate_num = num1;
            if(rate_num >= 7) {
            rate_num.style.color = "#008000"; // green
            } else if (rate_num >= 4) {
            rate_num.style.color = " #FFFF00"; // yellow
            } else {
            rate_num.style.color = " #FF0000"; // red
            }
            return rate_num;
            }
            </script>

    <figure class="wp-block-table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Service Rate</th>
                <th class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Secure Rate</td>
                <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><div class="Secure-Rate"><?php echo "<script> change_color_text($secure_num); </script>"?></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Price Rate</td>
                <td class="has-text-align-center" data-align="center"><div class="Price-Rate"><?php echo "<script> change_color_text($price_num); </script>"?></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </figure>
?>
```

So what I'm trying to do is that **if $secure_num is 8 then the number '8' (green color) should be echoed**, and if $price_num is 4 then the the number '4' (red) should be echoed on the screen. I don't use html format 'cause I'm writing this code on the wordpress theme code(mostly php file).

Comment: Please post complete HTML and JavaScript. In the code you posted you are declaring a variable called rate_num to which you assign the value of $sum variable. But thats not a HTML element so you cant change color.

Comment: you call function `change_color` which doesn't exist, You've created  `change_color_text `! So just add `_text` to your function name!

Comment: sorry to confuse you. I have put all the php code above as you said @Sudhir.

Comment: I changed the error as you advised me @TAHERElMehdi

Answer (score 1):

This code will definitely give an error, "cannot read value of undefined"

This has to do with DOM manipulation.
In this code, JavaScript engine doesn't understand what element style color you're trying to change.

A way to fix this will be

```
const rate_num = document.querySelector(".class")
```

Where .class is the class name of whatever text you're trying to change in the HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry but what line should I change the code? Should I change inside of the function or outside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

you can write this

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="demo"></div>
    <script>
    function change_color_text (num1) {
    var rate_num = num1;
    if(rate_num >= 7) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="green";
        document.getElementById('demo').style.color="green";
    } else if (rate_num >= 4) {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="yellow"; // yellow
        document.getElementById('demo').style.color="yellow";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="red" // red;
        document.getElementById('demo').style.color="red";
    }
    return rate_num;
    }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>


    <?php echo "<script> change_color_text(8) </script>"?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).